# 403 Forbidden on publishing page with webpart

Tags: web-part, access-denied, 403

We created bunch of web parts for our client. Initially we set up web application on port 1443 with NTLM and Forms authentication. Everything works ok.

Now we extended this web app to port 443, with forms authentication only. The problem is that when I try to access page with web part in the 443 application, browser shows me error 403 forbidden despite fact I'm logged in. What is more, anonymous access is enabled on web application and site collection. The problem does not exist when I do forms login and access the same page with webpart by 1443 application. Webpart works correclty also when page is accessed by anonymous user.

The other web part on the other hand shows:

```
Access denied to the path 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\443\App_Data' is denied
```

when accessed through web app on port 443. The problem does not exist when the same page with webpart is accessed by 1443 web application (also forms auth).

Any ideas what might cause such behavior?

PS.: We have another web app on port 443. Both web applications have host headers configured properly.

Comment: Have you correctly configured your Alternate Access Mappings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, problem was caused by faulty ASP.net profile provider. Extended web application didn't have profile provider configured properly (actually it didn't have configured default profile provider - see [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43501/sharepoint-2010-and-asp-profile-provider))

Answer (score 0):

I came across same error few days ago, in my case problem was with a web template I pasted in 12 hive which didn't appropriate permissions, e.g. you have to go to properties of folder and then add appropriate permissions, e.g. administrator..

While I was researching on this error I also came across one article that was asking to check the user your using for Application pool in IIS have appropriate permissions.